# Is there a way to stack a set of TIFF images and reconstruct into a 3D volume using mayavi?

Tags: python, image-processing, visualization, mayavi

I am trying to stack a set of .TIFF images (obtained from x-ray micro-tomography) into a 3D volume using mayavi, but i am not able get it.

I tried using mayavi.mlab.imshow(), but it just shows one image over another by  some distance apart. How to get an actual 3D volume?

```
from mayavi import mlab
import numpy as np
import cv2

path = "code\\NAC-IS-90D0"
mlab.clf()
arr = np.array([cv2.imread(path+str(i)+'.tif',0) for i in 
np.arange(15,20,1)])
j = 0
for i in range(5):
    obj = mlab.imshow(arr[i][:][:])
    obj.actor.position = [0, 0, j]      
    j+=5
```

This code only stacks one image file over another. Is there any way to visualize it as 3D volume, somehow making these images connected to one another??